# Show the series is convergent and find the limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Sequence of real numbers $a_n$ defined recursively with $a_1=1/2$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2}{a_n^2-a_n+1}$  for all $n \geq 1$.
Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is convergent and find its limit.
I have tried to convert the recursive form to explicit form but it's too difficult.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the following sequence $b_n = \frac{1}{a_n}$. Then
$$b_{n+1} =
\frac{a_n^2-a_n+1}{a_n^2} = 1 - \frac{1}{a_n}+ \frac{1}{a_n^2} = b_n^2-b_n+1
$$
so the sequence $b_n$ is an increasing sequence of natural numbers whose first terms are
$$2, \ 3, \ 7, \ 43, \ 1807, \ \dots$$

Partial sums have a curious pattern: if you denote $s_n = a_1 + \cdots + a_n$ you have

- $s_1 = \frac{1}{2} = 1 - \frac{1}{b_1} = 1- \frac{1}{b_2-1}$
- $s_2 = \frac{5}{6} = 1- \frac{1}{b_1b_2} = 1- \frac{1}{b_3-1}$
- $s_3 = \frac{41}{42} = 1- \frac{1}{b_1b_2b_3} = 1- \frac{1}{b_4-1}$
- $s_4 = \frac{1805}{1806} = 1- \frac{1}{b_1b_2b_3b_4} = 1- \frac{1}{b_5-1}$

So it seems that the sum of the series is $1$ and the partial sums are $s_n=1- a_1 \cdots a_n$

EDIT: Wikipedia says that this is called Sylvester Sequence. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence

Comment: Do i have to change the recursive form to explicit form to find it's limit ?

Comment: There is no closed form for the general term. You have to work recursively.

Comment: @Crostul May i ask a question? Is there any method to check that a given sequence has a closed form for the general term?

Comment: @ARUNA Actually no. I said that there is no explicit form because in my opinion the exercise is thought to be solved using induction. Maybe an explicit form exists... But are you able to find it?