# convergent series $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{1/a_k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

> The sequence $a_n$ is defined as:
> $$a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2, a_{n+1} = 1 + a_1a_2...a_{n-1}+\left(a_1a_2...a_{n-1} \right)^2  \text{ for all } n\ge 2$$
> Prove that the sequence $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n{1/a_k} $ is convergent and find $\lim s_n, n \rightarrow \infty$.

What I have done: I constructed two sequences ${\{b_1=1, b_n=n(n-1), n\ge2\} }$ and ${\{c_n=2^{n-1}, n \ge 1\}}$ such that $b_n \le a_n \le c_n$ and both $\sum_{k=1}^n{1/b_k}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^n{1/c_k} $ are convergent with limit 2. I'm interested to know if this is correct and if there are other solutions.

Comment: You might want to give the explicit sequences $b_{n}$ and $c_{n}$.

Comment: @mattos, I updated the post

Comment: This is Sylvester's sequence, see for instance https://oeis.org/A000058. Almost certainly a duplicate but I'm on my phone and can't search well.

Comment: The property you want to show to find the sum is: $\frac{1}{a_{n}} = \frac{1}{a_{n}-1}-\frac{1}{a_{n+1}-1}$ from which the sum follows by telescoping (given that you show that $a_n\to\infty$ which is not too hard).

Comment: Haven't found it on site but according to AoPS this is from Iran National Math Olympiad 1989 Second Round: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h381100p2110083

Comment: Does this answer your question (not the greatest quality, but [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171621) is also basically the same)? [Sum of a sequence following a pattern](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377130/sum-of-a-sequence-following-a-pattern)

Comment: @Integrand, it seems to be similar problem but not quite the same. Winther suggested that solution too but I don’t think his recursion is correct.

Comment: Can you compute the first few terms?